# issue with the MPRemoteCommandCenter in swift3

Tags: swift3, avfoundation

i have an issue for controlling on media from the command center in swift 3 i found solution on the stackoverflow web  but it's can't give me control on the video track or audio from background the following is my code :

```
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let mpRemoteControlCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
        mpRemoteControlCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
        mpRemoteControlCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.nextTrack))
        mpRemoteControlCenter.previousTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
        mpRemoteControlCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.prevTrack))
        mpRemoteControlCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
        mpRemoteControlCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.play))
}

   func play() {
        print("play")
    }
    func nextTrack(){
        print("next")
    }
    func prevTrack() {
        print("prev")
    }
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Xcode 8, you need to turn on Background Modes in Capabilities, and check "Audio, Airplay, and Picture in Picture".

Add this code to your `viewDidLoad()` as well

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    } catch {

    }
```

It should work after doing so.

Comment: Glad i can help